# Inserting at end of linked list and endless loop

Tags: c++, linked-list, infinite-loop

So I am working on a project for school and I am running into an issue where the head of the linked list is changing when I insert at the end, but I can't seem to identify where in my code this (obviously it has to be happening in the processVector function I created.

The idea is that I have a CSV file that contains the information for a patient. I use fstream to input the data from the CSV file into a vector of Patients. I then try to convert each element in the vector list into a node. Finally I try to display the lists.

When I run the code, it shows the head changing each time it adds a new node, but my thought was my code would be adding nodes to the end, not the beginning. What ultimately happens is when I run displayList, it just runs an endless loop showing the contents of the last node.

Code as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
#include <cassert> 

using namespace std;

const string fileName = "Patient.csv";

template <class Type>
struct Node
{
    Type info;
    Node<Type> *next;
};

template <class Type>
class LinkedList
{
    Node<Type> *head;
    int length;

public:
    LinkedList();
    LinkedList(const LinkedList&); // required by the Rule of Three
    //~LinkedList();
    LinkedList& operator=(const LinkedList&); // required by the Rule of Three
    void processVector(vector<Type>);
    void insert(const Type&);
    void remove(const Type&);
    void print(std::ostream &);
    void displayList();
    // other functions as required

private:
    /*Node<Type> *head;
    int length;*/
};

class PatientType
{
public:
    PatientType();
    PatientType(string patientSSN, string patientFName, string patientLName, string patientEmail, string patientNumber);
    string getPSSN();
    string getPFName();
    string getPLName();
    string getPEmail();
    string getPNumber();
    void setPatient(string PSSN, string PFName, string PLName, string PEmail, string PNumber);
    void loadList(vector<PatientType> &iList);

private:
    // Node<PatientType>* head; eliminated

    // private stuff that has no bearing on this example
    string pSSN;
    string pFName;
    string pLName;
    string pEmail;
    string pNumber;
};

template <class Type>
LinkedList<Type>::LinkedList()
{
    length = 0; //To keep track of the length to be O(1) otherwise it will be O(n) when we traverse throughout the whole linked list.
    head = NULL;  //The list is essentially empty
}
template <class Type>
void LinkedList<Type>::processVector(vector<Type> vecList)
{
    Node<PatientType> *newNode = new Node < PatientType >;
    int size = vecList.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        newNode->info = vecList[i];
        newNode->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL) //List empty
        {
            //newNode->info = vecList[i];
            //newNode->next = NULL;
            head = newNode;
            cout << "I'm in the if statement (line 87)" << endl;
            cout << "The head is: " << head->info.getPSSN() << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "I'm in the else statement (line 92)" << endl;
            Node<PatientType> *temp = head;
            while (temp->next != NULL)
            {
                temp = temp->next; //traverse the list
            }
            temp->next = newNode;
            cout << "The head is: " << head->info.getPSSN() << endl;
        }
        length++;
        cout << "Length is "<< length << endl;
    }
}
template <class Type>
void LinkedList<Type>::displayList()
{
    Node<PatientType> *temp;
    temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        cout << temp->info.getPSSN() << "\t" << temp->info.getPFName() << "\t" << temp->info.getPLName() << "\t" << temp->info.getPEmail() << "\t" << temp->info.getPNumber() << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

PatientType::PatientType()
{
    /*pSSN = "SSN";
    pFName = "First Name";
    pLName = "Last Name";
    pEmail = "Email";
    pNumber = "Phone Number";*/
}

PatientType::PatientType(string patientSSN, string patientFName, string patientLName, string patientEmail, string patientNumber)
{
    pSSN = patientSSN;
    pFName = patientFName;
    pLName = patientLName;
    pEmail = patientEmail;
    pNumber = patientNumber;
}

string PatientType::getPSSN()
{
    return pSSN;
}
string PatientType::getPFName()
{
    return pFName;
}
string PatientType::getPLName()
{
    return pLName;
}
string PatientType::getPEmail()
{
    return pEmail;
}
string PatientType::getPNumber()
{
    return pNumber;
}

void loadPatientList(vector<PatientType> &iList)
{
    ifstream infile;
    string filePSSN;
    string filePFName;
    string filePLName;
    string filePEmail;
    string filePNumber;

    infile.open(fileName);

    while (!infile.eof())
    {
        getline(infile, filePSSN, ',');
        getline(infile, filePFName, ',');
        getline(infile, filePLName, ',');
        getline(infile, filePEmail, ',');
        getline(infile, filePNumber, '\n');
        iList.push_back(PatientType(filePSSN, filePFName, filePLName, filePEmail, filePNumber));
    }
    infile.close();
}

int main()
{
    ifstream file(fileName);
    vector<PatientType> patientList;
    loadPatientList(patientList);
    LinkedList<PatientType> pList;

    pList.processVector(patientList);
    pList.displayList();


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think seeing the `insert()` function would be helpful.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I think the `void LinkedList<Type>::processVector(vector<Type> vecList)` function performs the insert

Comment: @JohnnyMopp He never calls `insert()`.

Comment: A minimal example that repro's the problem would be good.

Comment: i count only 2 times "required by the rule of three" ;)

Comment: Probably unrelated, but will bite you sooner or later, [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: please read about [mcve]. There is lots of code in your example that is unrelated to your problem. Creating a mcve will help you to spot mistakes easier and if not it helps us to help you

Comment: You only call `new` once in `processVector()`. So you are just inserting the same node over and over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're reusing the same  node each time through the `for` loop in `processVector`. You're setting `head` to that node, and then setting its `next` field to point to itself, resulting in a circular list.

You need to create a new `Node` each time. So move the line:

```
Node<PatientType> *newNode = new Node < PatientType >;
```

into the `for` loop.